# Programming Gekko to solve MINLP problem while having to reach a value with the objective function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, gekko

I am trying to build a prototype of an EMS for a PV system. I was using MILP solvers for my configuration, but the way I developed the problem and the objective function turned the problem into an MINLP, so I started using Gekko, which is amazing.

Right now the system has to decide whether it buys energy or not to produce green ammonia based on the production of hydrogen through electrolysis. The energy used for both processes (hydrogen electrolysis and Haber-Bosch to produce ammonia) comes from a solar farm and/or the grid (but in this case it must be bought). And then it has to decide the destination market for this ammonia trying to maximize the profit.

But I want to put another constraint, simulating that this system has to produce at least 30 M.T. (30000 kg) throughout a month. This is impossible using only the PV energy, so the system will have to buy energy in order to attain this objective. But it's also important to maximize the profit.

So in order to solve this I tried this code using two objective functions, trying to maximize production and profits, but I think Gekko just considered that it was more important to maximize the profit and didn't buy energy.

The question is: Is it possible to input some value that Gekko needs to reach with the objective function, but using the most optimized way to reach there?

I thought about writing some ifs and changing objective functions between them like: first maximize the production, if 30M.T. is reached, switch to profit maximization. But it doesn't seem to be the best option or the most optimized solution.

Plus: I used a while loop looking forward to reach the best optimization for each hour of the month. I don't know if this is the most "clean" way to do a loop with Gekko.

Here's my code so far (EDIT - I put the "if" idea in action)

```py
#Attempt using Gekko
from gekko import GEKKO
i=0 #counter for the while loop
contract_prod=30000 #kg

nh3_ue=[]#measures the percentage of ammonia sold to the European Union
nh3_usa=[]#measures the percentage of ammonia sold to the US
nh3_asia=[]#measures the percentage of ammonia sold to ASIA
nh3_br=[]#measures the percentage of ammonia sold to Brazil
max_profit=[]#measures the profit
p_buy = []#measures how much energy was bought
accumulate_prod=[]#measures accumulated production
prod_index=[]#measures the production in a specific hour

while i<=24:
#Initialize Model
  m = GEKKO()

#Set Global Options
  m.options.SOLVER=1 

# optional solver settings with APOPT
  m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 500', \
                    # minlp iterations with integer solution
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10', \
                    # treat minlp as nlp
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                    # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                    'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                    # maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']

#Parameters
  c_H2 = m.Param(value=4.5,name="LCOH")
  c_HB = m.Param(value=0.757,name="xCost_Haber-Bosch")
  p_ue = m.Param(value=1.602,name="Price_europe")
  p_usa = m.Param(value=1.323,name="Price_usa")
  p_asia = m.Param(value=0.84,name="Price_asia")
  p_br=m.Param(value=1.55,name="Price_brazil")
  per_min_br=m.Param(value=20,name="minimmum_brasil")
  perc=m.Param(value=100,name="total_percentage_ammonia")
  limit=m.Param(value=963070.78)#Electrolyzer limit
  p_ufvi=m.Param(p_ufv[0][i])#Energy from PV in ith hour
  c_Ci=m.Param(c_C[0][i])#Grid energ cost in ith hour

#Initialize Variables
  per_eur = m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100,name="ammonia_to_europe_percentage")
  per_usa = m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100,name="ammonia_to_usa_percentage")
  per_asia = m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100,name="ammonia_to_asia_percentage")
  per_br= m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100,name="ammonia_to_br_percentage")
  p_C = m.Var(value=100,lb=0,ub=963070.78,name="energy_bought")

#Equations
  m.Equation(per_eur+per_usa+per_asia+per_br+per_min_br<=perc)
  m.Equation(p_ufvi+p_C<=limit)

#Objective
  obj1 = m.Intermediate(per_eur*(p_ue-c_HB-c_H2/5.67)*(p_ufvi+p_C)/1108500
                        +per_usa*(p_usa-c_HB-c_H2/5.67)*(p_ufvi+p_C)/1108500
                        +per_asia*(p_asia-c_HB-c_H2/5.67)*(p_ufvi+p_C)/1108500
                        +(per_br+per_min_br)*(p_br-c_HB-c_H2/5.67)*(p_ufvi+p_C)/1108500
                        -c_Ci*p_C/1000000) #Profit
  obj2=m.Intermediate((p_ufvi+p_C)/11085) #Production

#Objective
  if i==0:
    m.Maximize(obj2)
  elif (accumulate_prod[i-1]<=contract_prod):
    m.Maximize(obj2)
  else:#maximizar lucro
    m.Maximize(obj1)
 
#Open the folder created with the results
  m.open_folder()

#Solve simulation
  try:
    m.solve(disp=True)    # solve
  except:
    print('Not successful')
    from gekko.apm import get_file 
    print(m._server)
    print(m._model_name)
    f = get_file(m._server,m._model_name,'infeasibilities.txt')
    f = f.decode().replace('\r','')
    with open('infeasibilities.txt', 'w') as fl:
        fl.write(str(f))

#Results
  nh3_ue.append(per_eur.value[0])
  nh3_usa.append(per_usa.value[0])
  nh3_asia.append(per_asia.value[0])
  nh3_br.append(per_br.value[0])
  p_buy.append(p_C.value[0])
  max_profit.append(obj1.value[0])
  prod_index.append(obj2.value[0])
  if i==0:
    acc=obj2.value[0]
  else:
    j=i-1
    acc=accumulate_prod[j]+obj2.value[0]
  accumulate_prod.append(acc)
  i=i+1
```

I hope you guys and @John Hedengren can save my day (LOL)

---

EDIT: Here are the values for p_ufv and c_C for 24 hours:

```
p_ufv:
[0        0.0
 1        0.0
 2        0.0
 3        0.0
 4        0.0
 5        0.0
 6        0.0
 7        78843.24
 8        330970.17
 9        558981.33
 10       735160.91
 11       800000.00
 12       800000.00
 13       800000.00
 14       800000.00
 15       755987.50
 16       587748.41
 17       366223.30
 18       113380.86
 19       0.0
 20       0.0
 21       0.0
 22       0.0
 23       0.0
Name: Potência W, Length: 24, dtype: float64]

c_C:
[0        379.39
 1        379.39
 2        379.39
 3        379.39
 4        379.39
 5        379.39
 6        379.39
 7        379.39
 8        379.39
 9        379.39
 10       379.39
 11       379.39
 12       379.39
 13       379.39
 14       379.39
 15       379.39
 16       379.39
 17       527.01
 18       527.01
 19       527.01
 20       527.01
 21       379.39
 22       379.39
 23       379.39
Name: Preco, Length: 24, dtype: float64]
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to make `obj2` a variable and put a lower bound on that part of the objective.

```py
obj2 = m.Var(lb=30000)
m.Equation(11085*obj2==(p_ufvi+p_C)) #Production
m.Maximize(obj2)
```

The model does not need to be redefined every cycle and it doesn't necessarily need the mixed integer solver `APOPT` (the `IPOPT` solver may also work). This gives a result that there is no feasible solution with these test values (not provided in the question):

```
# test values
p_ufv = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
c_C = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

```py
#Attempt using Gekko
from gekko import GEKKO
i=0 #counter for the while loop
contract_prod=30000 #kg

nh3_ue=[]#measures the percentage of ammonia sold to European Union
nh3_usa=[]#measures the percentage of ammonia sold to US
nh3_asia=[]#measures the percentage of ammonia sold to ASIA
nh3_br=[]#measures the percentage of ammonia sold to Brazil
max_profit=[]#measures the profit
p_buy = []#measures how much energy was bought
accumulate_prod=[]#measures accumulated production
prod_index=[]#measures the production in a specific hour

#Initialize Model
m = GEKKO()

#Set Global Options
m.options.SOLVER=1 

# optional solver settings with APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 500', \
                    # minlp iterations with integer solution
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10', \
                    # treat minlp as nlp
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                    # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                    'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                    # maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']

#Parameters
c_H2 = m.Param(value=4.5,name="LCOH")
c_HB = m.Param(value=0.757,name="xCost_Haber-Bosch")
p_ue = m.Param(value=1.602,name="Price_europe")
p_usa = m.Param(value=1.323,name="Price_usa")
p_asia = m.Param(value=0.84,name="Price_asia")
p_br=m.Param(value=1.55,name="Price_brazil")
per_min_br=m.Param(value=20,name="minimmum_brasil")
perc=m.Param(value=100,name="total_percentage_ammonia")
limit=m.Param(value=963070.78)#Electrolyzer limit
p_ufvi=m.Param()#Energy from PV in ith hour
c_Ci=m.Param()#Grid energ cost in ith hour

#Initialize Variables
per_eur = m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100,name="ammonia_to_europe_percentage")
per_usa = m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100,name="ammonia_to_usa_percentage")
per_asia = m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100,name="ammonia_to_asia_percentage")
per_br= m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100,name="ammonia_to_br_percentage")
p_C = m.Var(value=100,lb=0,ub=963070.78,name="energy_bought")

#Equations
m.Equation(per_eur+per_usa+per_asia+per_br+per_min_br<=perc)
m.Equation(p_ufvi+p_C<=limit)

#Objective
obj1 = m.Intermediate(per_eur*(p_ue-c_HB-c_H2/5.67)*(p_ufvi+p_C)/1108500 \
                        +per_usa*(p_usa-c_HB-c_H2/5.67)*(p_ufvi+p_C)/1108500 \
                        +per_asia*(p_asia-c_HB-c_H2/5.67)*(p_ufvi+p_C)/1108500 \
                        +(per_br+per_min_br)*(p_br-c_HB-c_H2/5.67)*(p_ufvi+p_C)/1108500 \
                        -c_Ci*p_C/1000000) #Profit
m.Maximize(obj1)

obj2 = m.Var(lb=30000)
m.Equation(11085*obj2==(p_ufvi+p_C)) #Production
m.Maximize(obj2)

# test values
p_ufv = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
c_C = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]

while i<=5:
 
  p_ufvi.value = p_ufv[0][i]
  c_Ci.value = c_C[0][i]


  #Solve simulation
  try:
    m.solve(disp=True)    # solve
  except:
    print('Not successful')
    from gekko.apm import get_file 
    print(m._server)
    print(m._model_name)
    f = get_file(m._server,m._model_name,'infeasibilities.txt')
    f = f.decode().replace('\r','')
    with open('infeasibilities.txt', 'w') as fl:
        fl.write(str(f))

  #Results
  nh3_ue.append(per_eur.value[0])
  nh3_usa.append(per_usa.value[0])
  nh3_asia.append(per_asia.value[0])
  nh3_br.append(per_br.value[0])
  p_buy.append(p_C.value[0])
  max_profit.append(obj1.value[0])
  prod_index.append(obj2.value[0])
  if i==0:
    acc=obj2.value[0]
  else:
    j=i-1
    acc=accumulate_prod[j]+obj2.value[0]
  accumulate_prod.append(acc)
  i=i+1
```

The name `c_HB = m.Param(value=0.757,name="Cost_Haber-Bosch")` creates an error because the interpreter is looking for an opening parenthesis on the function `cos(x)`. This is only an issue when naming the variables with `name=` because `APMonitor` has reserved keywords.

```
 *** Error in syntax of function string: Missing opening parenthesis
```

Switching to `xCost_Haber_Bosch` resolves this error.

It looks like the problem should be optimized simultaneously with `IMODE=6`, not in steps. This changes the `obj2` constraint to be active only on the final step.

```py
obj2 = m.Var(0)
p = np.zeros(len(m.time))
p[-1] = 1
final = m.Param(p)
m.Equation(final*(obj2-30000)>=0)
m.Equation(11085*obj2==(p_ufvi+p_C)) #Production
m.Maximize(obj2)
```

Both `APOPT` and `IPOPT` report an infeasible solution, but it may just be the test values that I used.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
i=0 #counter for the while loop
contract_prod=30000 #kg

nh3_ue=[]#measures the percentage of ammonia sold to European Union
nh3_usa=[]#measures the percentage of ammonia sold to US
nh3_asia=[]#measures the percentage of ammonia sold to ASIA
nh3_br=[]#measures the percentage of ammonia sold to Brazil
max_profit=[]#measures the profit
p_buy = []#measures how much energy was bought
accumulate_prod=[]#measures accumulated production
prod_index=[]#measures the production in a specific hour

#Initialize Model
m = GEKKO()

m.time = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
m.options.IMODE = 6

#Set Global Options
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000

#Parameters
c_H2 = m.Param(value=4.5,name="LCOH")
c_HB = m.Param(value=0.757,name="xCost_Haber-Bosch")
p_ue = m.Param(value=1.602,name="Price_europe")
p_usa = m.Param(value=1.323,name="Price_usa")
p_asia = m.Param(value=0.84,name="Price_asia")
p_br=m.Param(value=1.55,name="Price_brazil")
per_min_br=m.Param(value=20,name="minimmum_brasil")
perc=m.Param(value=100,name="total_percentage_ammonia")
limit=m.Param(value=963070.78)#Electrolyzer limit
p_ufvi=m.Param()#Energy from PV in ith hour
c_Ci=m.Param()#Grid energ cost in ith hour

#Initialize Variables
per_eur = m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100,name="ammonia_to_europe_percentage")
per_usa = m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100,name="ammonia_to_usa_percentage")
per_asia = m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100,name="ammonia_to_asia_percentage")
per_br= m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100,name="ammonia_to_br_percentage")
p_C = m.Var(value=100,lb=0,ub=963070.78,name="energy_bought")

#Equations
m.Equation(per_eur+per_usa+per_asia+per_br+per_min_br<=perc)
m.Equation(p_ufvi+p_C<=limit)

#Objective
obj1 = m.Intermediate(per_eur*(p_ue-c_HB-c_H2/5.67)*(p_ufvi+p_C)/1108500 \
                        +per_usa*(p_usa-c_HB-c_H2/5.67)*(p_ufvi+p_C)/1108500 \
                        +per_asia*(p_asia-c_HB-c_H2/5.67)*(p_ufvi+p_C)/1108500 \
                        +(per_br+per_min_br)*(p_br-c_HB-c_H2/5.67)*(p_ufvi+p_C)/1108500 \
                        -c_Ci*p_C/1000000) #Profit
m.Maximize(obj1)


obj2 = m.Var(0)
p = np.zeros(len(m.time))
p[-1] = 1
final = m.Param(p)
m.Equation(final*(obj2-30000)>=0)
m.Equation(11085*obj2==(p_ufvi+p_C)) #Production
m.Maximize(obj2)

# test values
p_ufv = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
c_C = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
 
p_ufvi.value = p_ufv[0][i]
c_Ci.value = c_C[0][i]


#Solve simulation
try:
  m.solve(disp=True)    # solve
except:
  print('Not successful')
  from gekko.apm import get_file 
  print(m._server)
  print(m._model_name)
  f = get_file(m._server,m._model_name,'infeasibilities.txt')
  f = f.decode().replace('\r','')
  with open('infeasibilities.txt', 'w') as fl:
      fl.write(str(f))
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the answer. 
I didn't test the code with the names of the variables in English. I was writing in Portuguese and switched to English to turn the code more understandable for most people. So I didn't have a problem with Cos(x). Anyway, it's good to know that.
I redefined the model in every cycle because when I tried to loop just the values, the current objective function value was added to its predecessor.
Finally, turning obj2 into a var or Using the "time+ IMODE=6" idea sadly returned me a "no feasible solution" status even with my test values.

Comment: Although it didn't work for me, I will edit the question providing the data (test values). And the code which is working wight now with the "if" idea.